# matlab multidimensional array to excel

Tags: excel, matlab, multidimensional-array, export-to-excel

I have a Matlab script with an output of a multidimensional array LCOE (3 dimensions) of size 16:12:34. This output needs to be written to Excel, therefore I use xlswrite.

I have tried this:

```
T = LCOE(:,:,1);
xlswrite('filename', T, 'sheetname', 'B2');
```

This does what it's supposed to, but only writes one table to excel, and I would like to write all 34 tables to excel underneath each other, spaced by `2 blank rows.

Then, I tried this:

```
for y = 1:34
    T = LCOE(:,:,y)
    xlswrite('filename', T, 'sheetname', strcat('B', num2str(2+(y-1)*18)));
```

This works, but is very slow, since matlab writes each table separately to excel. Is there a faster way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `xlswrite` again and again. Dump all the values of a 3D matrix into a 2D matrix and add rows of `NaN`s so that when you write that to excel file, you get 2 blank rows.

Following code improves the execution time by the factor of more than 10.

```
LCOE = 100*rand(16,12,34);   % Taking random values for LCOE
T = NaN(18*34-2 ,12);        % 1. Pre-allocation    2. 16+2 = 18 

% Following loop dumps all the values of 3D matrix into a 2-D followed by 2 rows of NaN 
% to leave 2 blank rows in excel file. 
for k = 1:34
    T(18*(k-1)+[1:16], :) =  LCOE(:,:,k); 
end
xlswrite('filename', T, 'sheetname', 'B2'); % Writing the Excel file
```

In my system, my code takes about 1 second to execute while your code takes about 10.5 seconds. So that's a significant difference.